# C beginner for-loop output issue

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, eof

I am new to C (self-learning).
When I execute this for-loop function when I type 'hello' the output will be 012345. However it skips to last print function outside of the for-loop?

```
int main() {

    int c;


    for (c = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++c) {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }

    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
hello
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: It depends on what an `EOF` is on your system.  You're probably pressing `Ctrl+C` which terminates the program.

Comment: Your code works as expected. What output do you expect?

Comment: Explain what keys exactly you press like: `[h]` `[e]` `[l]` `[l]` `[o]` `[Enter]` ....

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: make the last printf a little different, ie: `printf("and finally %d\n", c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*When I execute this `for`-loop function and I type `'hello'` the output will be `012345`*".

What do you expect else? `c` just get incremented by each iteration, starting at `0`.

> "*However it skips to the last print function outside of the `for`-loop?*"

No, it doesn´t. In fact, It isn´t even out of the `for` loop. The newline made by the press to `Enter` doesn´t let you break out of the loop; only a signalized `EOF` is doing that.

So, the program isn´t even terminated. It stucks in the loop.

You need to signalize `EOF` with `CTRL + D` on Linux or `CTRL + Z` on Windows to break out of the loop.

Comment: Exactly! How does it break the for-loop?

Comment: @programmeurNED With `EOF` like for example `CTRL + D` or `CTRL + Z`.

Comment: @programmeurNED you need to enter EOF (Ctrl+D on Linux/Mac, Ctrl+Z on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not skipping anything.

Note: you are printing `c` which is integer (not character, if that is what you want). So, input `"hello"` has 5 characters: so, output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Then, as there is newline character `'\n'` as you pressed `enter` (there is your output `5`). However, you loop never exits, unless you force program to do so (I mean, interrupting with Ctrl +C). If you, test again your code, and input data even after `"hello"`, you will see that, you are still in the loop.

Comment: When I debug the program, it stops after the for-loop. Not printing the last statement

Comment: Your run and debug outputs are different?

Answer (score 1):

Change your program to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
  int c;
  int ch;

  for (c = 0; (ch = getchar()) != EOF; ++c) {
    printf("%d %d\n", c, ch);
  }

  printf("%d %d\n", c, ch);    
  return 0;
}
```

Now you should understand yourself what happens.

Comment: Thank you @Jabberwocky. I dont quiete understand why the last line --> Printf("End: %d\n, c"); doesn't print

Comment: @programmeurNED what key do you press?? What is your platform?

Answer (score 0):

The while loop doesn't end when you type `hello` and presses Enter, because `getchar()` still won't be equal to `EOF`. So the loop will continue with getchar() waiting to read new characters.

You need to press Ctrl+Z on Windows' cmd.exe, or Ctrl+D on Linux's terminal, to proceed with the execution of the program without writing any character to the input, then `getchar` will fail to read a character and return `EOF`, finally exiting the loop. Once it is out of the loop the final `printf` call will be made before ending the program.

Alternatively you could change the condition to make the loop end when `getchar` reads a new line character `\n`, instead of when it fails to read a character, so that the loop will end after you press Enter:

```
int main() {

    int c;


    for (c = 0; getchar() != '\n'; ++c) {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }

    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see what you're tryng to do, but first of all i'd declare "c" as a char , this way you're doing an implicit cast to char, which is allowed in C language, but should be avoided.

My best guess would be that you'r compiler (i suppose mingw on windows) is not telling you what's going on exactly, try this:

When you build (compile) something outside linux for C language do as follows :

" gcc -o nameoftheexecutable file.c -Wall " and to execute it " ./nameoftheexecutable

That -Wall will print out all warnings to the console, including EOF warnings.

By doing this, and understanding what IDE or Environment are you programming in, we can help you out.